# What does the symbol $\|\ \|^2_2$ mean?

Tags: probability-theory, notation

If the *distance* is given by:
$$\|X_m-X_n\|^2_2.$$

Could anyone precisely explain the `meaning` of the **symbol**  $\|\ \|^2_2$  ?

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/).

Comment: It **depends on the context**. People only exposed to metric spaces will certainly think of it as the square of the $L^2$-norm. In that part of math tat would be the expectation. But, in another context it could mean something else. Basically whatever the author meant! That's why textbooks often include a page or two where notational conventions are spelled out (possibly including pointers to the pages where they are introduced).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\|x\|_2$ means the $2$-norm, which is $$\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}$$

while the $2$ on top, is its square, so both result in:
$$\|x\|^2_2=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2.$$

Overall, it means the sum of square of the components.

Comment: So in this case, it would mean:
for all m, for all n, take the squared difference between xm and xn.. and then sum everything?

Comment: First, are $x_m$ and $x_n$ vectors? If so , when we evaluate $\|x_m-x_n\|^2$, the $m$ and $n$ are fixed.  We compute $x_m-x_n$, then we sum up the square of each component and we sum them up.

Answer (score 1):

In general, $|| \cdot ||_2$ is called the $L^2$-norm, which is a functional from the function space $L^2(\Omega,{\cal A}, \mu)$ to $\Bbb R$ defined by $f \mapsto (\int |f|^2 \,{\rm d}\mu)^{1/2}$, provided that the integral exists.  This is probably the case when you see $$||X_m - X_n||_2$$ since random variables are usually denoted with capital letters in [probability-theory](/questions/tagged/probability-theory).

In particular, when $\Omega = \Bbb{N}$, $\mu$ is the counting measure, we have $||f||_2 = (\int |f|^2 \,{\rm d}\mu)^{1/2} = (\sum_n |f_n|^2)^{1/2}$.  This is the case if you actually mean
$$||x_m-x_n||_2$$ a norm of vector.

Remark: It's *hard* to distinguish $X$ from $x$ in your drawing.  That's the reason why I promote the use of $\rm \LaTeX$ in *all* levels of math writing.